# Allow users to disable notifications Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I don't know if this can be done but I have a scheduler/diary app that allows the user to add/remove items. When the user adds an item, they are given an option to set a notification for either 1 hour, 30 mins, or 15 mins before the event time or else to not be notified. I am using an alarm manager with a broadcast receiver to handle this.

I want to display an option in the app menu to enable/disable notifications; i.e. if an alarm is scheduled to sound in 15 mins it should not happen. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [NotificationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html) class. When you set your notification you can provide a notification id like this:

```
mNotificationManager.notify(id, notification)
```

If you later want to cancel this notification(i.e. like in your case, if a user has selected an option to disable notifications) you would need to use

```
mNotificationManager.cancel(id)
```

Or you could use cancelAll() to cancel all notifications:

```
mNotificationManager.cancelAll ()
```

Let me know if this helps.